# Vuejs have multiple components sharing variables and functions

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Right this is more about practice, I haven't really got a working scenario but I can provide an example. Imagine Facebook messenger, you have a chat widget in the header where you can quickly view and respond to messages. You can also click view all to take you off to the messages page.

So to me I can see myself having two Vue components, they're more sibling than parent and child as one would be used on all pages and the other simply on the messages page.

```
<chat></chat> and <chat-widget></chat-widget>
```

Now from what I can see, across the widget and the chat window itself is functions that would operate in the same way, maybe they'll have slightly different templates because of where they are loaded but somethings straight of the bat would be:

```
messages() {}
compose() {}
validate() {}
```

These are just some examples as I use Laravel as my backend I would be using axios to send requests between my Vue frontend and my backend (database).

Ideally, I wouldn't want these components to duplicate it's functions, so should I simply duplicate them or is there a way where i can store some sort of parent functions?

One problem is because of async ajax requests I can't simply call a function that returns say the messages for me to bind, at least, I don't think I can.

Just looking for some guidance on how I can best do this with Vue so that I'm not duplicating identical functionality within my components.

Comment: You should make a container / list component, what has many message component.

Comment: I can't visualise how that would work could you give an example? I presume your saying that this component would store say the messages and the message function and the other components directly use those functions and variables? Just don't understand how can you do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use composition to create a "base/abstract" component from which other components can extend:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#extends

```
var CompA = { ... }
// extend CompA without having to call `Vue.extend` on either
var CompB = {
  extends: CompA,
  ...
}
```

You can inherit the functionality from the "base/abstract" class or override parts of the functionality of the parent.

Another thing you could do is to create mixins:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#ad

This is helpful if your components need to share functionality but are not largely the same. If you were to use `extend` in those cases you would likely override the majority of base functionality to these are a better in that case.

Of course nothing would stop you from simply extracting commonly used methods into a separate file and importing them in your components directly.

Comment: Alright, mixins look really nice. So i suppose i could put it in a .js file and export var mixinName {} and import it? Also i see that i can call functions which is nice could i create data and be able to do like this.messages because that would be awesome!

Comment: Yes you can import it just like you described, the functionality of the mixin will get merged with the functionality of the component. You could also set `data` and all other options that Vue components provide.From the documentation: `A mixin object can contain any component options`.

Comment: Curious, if say i have 3 components that will use the mixin or extend. Should i import it in each component or make it globally available?

Comment: `Use global mixins sparsely and carefully, because it affects every single Vue instance created, including third party components`. If you would use a global mixin it would be to add bare minimal logic like a log handler or something like that. I would not ever use global mixins since they affect every instance. That is unless you are 100% sure you will stick to these 3 components and your package will not use third party components.

Comment: So like when i create say a CMS i create one Vue instance and just load all my components into it. Is this bad practice? Should I have a chat.js file and have just my chat vue instance in there or what's best? Or is it just about user preference.